# When duplicating a target in XCode, changes in the new file still also appear in the old file

Tags: c, xcode, version-control, duplicates, targets

The files must be in the same path so I'm wondering how to work around this so that whenever I duplicate a target, a new copy is made that can be edited without changing the original. This would make the creation of new versions of existing applications much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Targets are not used to create different versions of apps (as in v1.0, v1.1, etc). They are used to be compiled to different binaries using the same shared code.

Here are common uses for targets:

- iOS target + OS X target
- Lite app target + Full app target
- iPhone app target + iPad app target
- Unit tests target
- Static library target

If you want to keep track of the different versions of your app (again version as in v1.0, v1.1, etc), then you should use a versioning system (such as git or svn), or make snapshots of your project for each version. Personally, I recommend using git.